# Android Suggestion TextField

Tags: android, input, user-input, textfield, suggestbox

I'm trying to design a user form and I was wondering if it's possible to create a TextField that when the user clicks on it a dropdown list appears with suggestions ( based on previous values entered by the user ) 
and the user has the choice to either pick on of the suggestions or writes his own in the text field .

Thank you

Comment: Please refer this link i hope you will get full solution:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Comment: I don't get it why people down vote some questions for no aparent reason, so i just up vote it

Comment: Yeah i think that'll work , but is it possible to filter the suggestions ? For example if the user types in the word " New York " I want a specific list of words to appear

Answer (score 1):

You can Use [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

An *editable text view* that shows completion suggestions `automatically while the user is typing`. The list of suggestions is displayed in a drop down menu from which the user can choose an item to replace the content of the edit box with.

Check Demo [android_auto_complete](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm)

Comment: Is it possible to customize the suggestions ?